# How do I send accelerometer (ADXL335) signals (x, y and z) via xbee?

Tags: wireless, xbee, psoc

I want to send the signals from a 3 axis accelerometer (ADXL335) to a PSoC3 via Xbee modules (S2).

What configurations do I need for each Xbees and can I send each of the signals (x, y and z) directly? If yes, then how? Would I need a separate microcontroller to convert analog signals to digital signals, or are the ADCs on the Xbees sufficient to do the job?

Comment: It is customary in English to capitalize "I" when referring to yourself. I have edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The ADXL335 outputs analog data so you can use the ADC on the xbee 
look at this [Guide](http://www.electronics-lab.com/projects/sensors/009/)